# pytest does not pass the test

Tags: pytest, filenotfounderror

file_workers.py

```
def read_from_file(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f_o:
        return f_o.readlines()
```

test_file_workers.py

```
from my_funcs.file_workers import read_from_file


def test_read_from_file():
    test_data = ['one\n', 'two\n','three\n']
    assert test_data == read_from_file('testfile.txt')
```

testfile.txt

```
one
two
three
```

I've tried everything but the test doesn't pass

The test must pass[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Instead, just copy the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) as a code block into the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: this is what a debugger is for... and the print function... you could also install a plugin for pytest like pytest-clarity that provides more information in the error logs. Make sure there aren't any empty lines at the end of the file... many IDE's insert them automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it's because `test_data` is a list (and what you're comparing it to is not a list)? I'd say try a string instead.